# Unable to create new project in angular

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

**I am using angular version 6 and nodejs v8.11
when i try to create new in angular, i get following error**
    Console log:

```
Unable to save binary /home/amit/demo/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-57 : { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/amit/demo/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
> node-sass@4.9.0 postinstall /home/amit/demo/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js
```

Comment: Seem you have no permission. Do you have rights on this folder?

Comment: Try to create using sudo command.

Comment: what command you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You are having permission issue with you command, you can solve it by using `sudo` prefix to your command:

if your command is :

```
npm install
```

use:

```
sudo npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

Run following commands

```
npm i -g npm-check-updates
npm-check-updates -u
npm install
```